# What's the correct way to create a global iron:router subscription?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I need a particular subscription for every route in my app, this works but I'm unsure if it is correct?

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('locations');
    this.next();
});
```

Also, is there a way to waitOn() globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare any options that you can set on a route on a global level by using the `Router.configure({});` . To use your example above:

```
Router.configure({
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('locations');
    }
});
```

The above will give you the specified subscription for all routes in your application by using the `waitOn` option in a global route context. For more information about all of the other options that you can set for routes on a global level, check [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#global-default-options) out.